# Change background colors of each Items in navigation Menu

Tags: android, user-interface, navigation-drawer, navigationitem

Hello any one can please help me out , I want to change background color for each items in the menu ,

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/mybooks"
        android:title="My Books"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/myInfo"
        android:title="Info" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/myfriends"
        android:title="My Friends" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/myQuiz"
        android:title="Game" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/myHobby"
        android:title="Hobbies" />

</group>
```

How Can I achieve it just background color to any color code "Not onClick change" just static background colors for each items